# Increase resolution of generated hill shade on QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, resolution

I want to export a hill shade (GeoTIFF) created from a DEM as an image for printing, but the resolution of the hill shade is way too low (900 columns, 1450 lines).

Any way to upscale it?

I tried `raster > projection > warp`, checked 'change size' and put higher numbers but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: One thing to try first. Right click on the hillshade layer in the layers panel, go Properties -> Style -> Resampling. Under 'Zoomed: in' select Bilinear, then set 'Oversampling' to (say) 6.

Comment: this smoothens the image (goes from pixelated to blurry) but doesn't increase the resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the number of pixels will only make the file larger but will not enhance the quality of the raster. You will be merely dividing each pixel. Besides, the number of lines and columns does not reflect the resolution of the raster. It all comes down to the area that one pixel represents on the ground. So if the ground resolution of the hillshade is the same as the original DEM there's not much you can do.

Comment: right. my bad. I mixed this DEM with another of the same area but a much better resolution.